# Where can i get full time tutorial on sculpting characters in blender

Tags: sculpting

Guy, I started learning blender last year, and after seeing many tutorials, I am good at making interiors, but now I whant to learn making stylized character, I have searched all over youtube, but I am not getting clearly explained full time tutorial, I am liking to do character like pixar's character. Where can I find one tutorial

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a tutorial request which is [off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic).

Comment: instead of beginning with sculpting you could also begin with low-poly modeling, you'll find a lot of tutorials on this topic, then if you want you can duplicate, sculpt details and bake the normals

Answer (score 1):

best tutorial i have saved is this masterpiece, if you want to get into the basics, i recomend it to get from point A to B
-Blender Sculpting Tutorial: Full Advanced Creature Creation Workflow-
https://youtu.be/tQfFlzHJJ88

if you want to get more theory or character specific to humanoids or alike i recommend check more zbrush tuts, you can do most stuff there in blender anyway like this

-Sculpting Disney characters is THIS EASY?-
https://youtu.be/FXsGNRW6hZs